# Is it possible to add a string to a "requests.get" function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Im trying to add an input string function like this,

```
r = requests.get('https://www.roblox.com/profile?userid=' + userid)
userid = input("Please enter a valid user ID: ")
print(r.text[0:100])
```

It doesn't work for me and I believe I am doing something wrong.

I want to make it so when the person types in a valid userid it adds it into the "requests.get" function and basically makes it apart of the url.

Comment: It would work if you added it to the url *after* the user had actually input it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare userid before you add it to your string. The following code will work.

```
userid = input("Please enter a valid user ID: ")
r = requests.get('https://www.roblox.com/profile?userid=' + userid)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Use `params` to pass query params instead of encoding it in the URL

Comment: Like so: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the input before.

```
userid = input("Please enter a valid user ID: ")
r = requests.get('https://www.roblox.com/profile?userid=' + str(userid))
print(r.text[0:100])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the order of the steps?

- Ask for the input and store it as `userid`
- Add that to the URL as part of the `requests.get()`

Python (and most programming languages) tend to evaluate steps in order, from the top down, so the order of the statements is often important.

```
    userid = input("Please enter a valid user ID: ")
    r = requests.get('https://www.roblox.com/profile?userid=' + userid)
    print(r.text[0:100])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, userid variable is not defined so you have a compilation-like error, just change the position of the statements like so

```
userId = input()
r = requests.get(f"url?id={userId}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of your commands.
When the `r = requests.get('https://www.roblox.com/profile?userid=' + userid)` is executed, the request is already done, you can't edit it.
Try something like this:

```
userid = input("Please enter a valid user ID: ")
r = requests.get('https://www.roblox.com/profile?userid=' + userid)
print(r.text[0:100])
```